# SVG Graph Generated Using D3.js disappearing when scrolling in Safari

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg, d3.js

I have a Rails webapp currently deployed at http://orbit-analytics.herokuapp.com/user/2990 which utilizes D3.JS and JavaScript to generate an SVG graph of the specific user's uploads with relation to time. The graph renders correctly in Chrome, Safari, and Firefox but highlighting the tick labels or scrolling can cause parts of the graph to disappear in Safari (but not Chrome or Firefox). This isn't a problem on another page with a similar graph, available at http://orbit-analytics.herokuapp.com/video/10.

Is this a Safari issue or some problem with my code? Thanks.

Comment: Your d3 code looks fine, and removing your CSS seems to fix the problem. I'll see if I can find something that doesn't look right.

Comment: Upon further examination, it seems like removing `stroke` from `line` fixes your problem (although it removes your lines). Can't really figure out why - hopefully that points you in a direction though.

Comment: Thank you, that was the nudge I needed in the right direction. Solved by adding that style to the gridlines using d3 instead of CSS although I have no idea why that worked. If you post that as an answer I'll accept it.

Comment: Also, would you have any idea how to add the minor gridlines seen on the graph at http://orbit-analytics.herokuapp.com/video/10? I'm struggling to get that to work for some reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is fixed when you remove the `stroke` property from `line` in your CSS. As [you mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11528291/svg-graph-generated-using-d3-js-disappearing-when-scrolling-in-safari#comment15242728_11528291), you can directly apply this style with the style function.

As far as adding minor lines goes, look into using `axis.tickSubdivide([n])`. If not you will probably find your answer in the [Axis](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/SVG-Axes) component.